# GKE cluster upgrade by switching to a new pool: will inter-cluster service communication fail?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

From this article(https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/Kubernetes-best-practices-upgrading-your-clusters-with-zero-downtime.html) I learnt that it is possible to create **a new node pool**, and cordon and drain old nodes one by one, so that workloads get re-scheduled to new nodes in the new pool.

To me, a new node pool seems to indicate a new cluster. The reason: we have two node pools in GKE, and they're listed as two separate clusters.

My question is: after the pods under a service get moved to a new node, if that service is being called from other pods in the old node, will this inter-cluster service call fail?

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a new cluster per se. You upgrade the master(s) and then you create a new node pool with nodes that have a newer version. Make sure the new node pool shares the same network as the original node pool.

If you have a service with one replica (one pod) if that pod is living in one of the nodes you are upgrading you need to allow time for Kubernetes to create a new replica on a different node that is not being upgraded. For that time, your service will be unavailable.

If you have a service with multiple replicas chances are that you won't see any downtime unless for some odd reason all your replicas are scheduled on the same node.

Recommendation: scale your resources which serve your services (Deployments, DaemonSets, StatefulSets, etc) by one or two replicas before doing node upgrades.

StatefulSet tip: You will have some write downtime if you are running something like mysql in a master-slave config when you reschedule your mysql master.

Comment: I was asking specifically about the approach of "creating a new pool and migrate workloads over", not about "upgrade nodes in existing pool". I'm not sure how relevant your answer is for the scenario I mentioned.

Comment: A new node pool is just a new set of machines, so you basically drain all your machines in the old node pool and Kubernetes will gradually move the workloads, either using or not using node pool. The way pods talk to each other is the same. Make sure the node pool in the same subnet as the old node pool.

Comment: The reason I thought creating a new pool means creating a new cluster is because, when I run "gcloud container clusters list", I saw multiple clusters, each cluster corresponding to a node pool. Plus when I run "kubectl get nodes" command I only see nodes in only one of my pools. Am I missing something? Or were we talking about different concepts of a cluster?

Comment: Oh, you have multiple Kubernetes clusters looks like. GKE doesn't have a thing for you to move workloads from one cluster to another. You'll have to schedule that with some sort of downtime. If you don't want to any downtime (or minimal downtime) you'll have to duplicate everything on a new cluster and put a Load Balancer layer on top of both clusters. Can be done but it requires more surgery.

Comment: The Google link in my original question does mention an approach of moving workloads from one pool to another pool.

Comment: But on the same GKE cluster

Comment: Be able to creating another node pool on the same GKE cluster seems what I really wanted(and thus makes my original question invalid). But is there an option that lets us choose whether the new pool will be in the same GKE cluster?

Comment: I think it just assumes that when you click on the 'Upgrade cluster' using node pools checkbox. GKE should do it automatically. My answer was more about explaining what would happen under the hood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180488/discussion-between-twimo-and-rico).

Comment: For "Make sure the new node pool shares the same network as the original node pool", does it suffice if I set --zone of the new pool to the same value of the current pool? Or there's some other parameter I should set?

Answer (score 0):

Note that creating a new node Pool does not create a new cluster. You can have multiple node pools within the same cluster. Workloads within the different node pools will still interact with each other since they are in the same cluster.

[gcloud container node-pools create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) (the command to create node pools) requires that you specify the --cluster flag so that the new node pool is created within an existing cluster.

So to answer the question directly, following the steps from that Google link will not cause any service interruption nor will there be any issues with pods from the same cluster communicating with each other during your migration.